# In ESB, did Vader sense Leia instead of Luke when he was chasing the Falcon?

Tags: star-wars, darth-vader, luke-skywalker, the-empire-strikes-back, princess-leia

In ESB, at the end of Hoth's attack, Vader saw the Falcon take off.

He's looking for Luke Skywalker. For him, Luke is on the ship, according to this:

> "Our pursuit ships have sighted the Millennium Falcon, my lord. It has
>   entered an asteroid field.” “Asteroids don’t concern me, Admiral,”
>   Vader said as he slowly clenched his fist. “I want that ship, not
>   excuses. How long until you will have Skywalker and the others in the
>   Millennium Falcon?”

(ESB - Novelisation)

Why is he certain that Luke is onboard of the Falcon? He hasn't seen him...

Has he sensed, via the Force, that *a Skywalker* was onboard?

If so, was it not Luke, but rather Leia?

Comment: This appears to be an embellishment by the novel as only a shortened version of the dialog is in the film.

Comment: The dupe indicates that Vader didn't sense *anything*. He merely assumed that Luke was on board.